# How can I automatically draw a circle on each node of a path in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, path

In a drawing in Inkscape I have a path and I need to have a circle on each node of the path, like this:

[image: path with a circle on each node]

I could draw and move them manually snapping the centre of circles to the nodes, but I have several nodes, so this would take much time.

Is there a way to draw the circles *automatically* on each node of the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert beginning-, middle- and end markers to the path:

[image]

Every node gets a marker. Circular marker is centered at the node.

The markers are not easily editable, you must choose from a limited selection of sizes and styles.

You can apply Path > Stroke to Path and ungroup to get the circles separated for edits. The path loses its editability, so have a spare copy.

ADD: User Billy Kerr reminded in his comment that you can draw your own shapes and use them as markers. See the discussion below.

Comment: You can create custom markers in Inskcape quite easily using Object > Objects to marker.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks, but is it really implemented? My shape vanishes after applying Objects to Marker as some tutorials say https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom-markers.html  but it has never appeared in the markers collection. I have Inkscape version 1.0 portable.

Comment: Yes, it definitely works in Inskcape 1.0 portable (that's what I use too) - see [example here](https://imgur.com/skW4bYz). The shape is supposed to disappear. It should be at the top of the markers drop down, you may have to scroll up to find it. The preview of the marker can sometimes look cropped to a square, maybe a little glitch there.

Comment: The problem is solved. If the custom marker happens to be bigger than the biggest standard marker it's shown as a dot in the list. Thanks for the help. I insert your comment to the answer.