# Inkscape scripting and automation: nodes?

Tags: inkscape, automation, script

How does Inkscape handle nodes in scripting? Or can the nodes be written out in some way? Or perhaps there is a better place to ask about this:

I have a simple manual clicking routine that seems a good candidate to automate using Inkscape scripting:

[image: Image of several circles each centered on different points on a bezier curve]

1. Draw one circle.
2. Move the circle so the center snaps onto the first node in a list.
3. Repeat for the next node until the number of nodes is reached.

This works so far, thus my interest in Inkscape, however, there are a number of problems that I think will be solved if the nodes are worked with differently. I have read/tried:

[GitHub repository: Simple Inkscape Scripting](https://github.com/spakin/SimpInkScr)

Also see:

- [Inkscape.org: Simple Inkscape Scripting](https://inkscape.org/%7Epakin/%E2%98%85simple-inkscape-scripting)
- [Tutorial – Inkscape Scripts](https://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2020/239/Magic-Circle)
- [Inkscape wiki: Using the Command Line](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Using_the_Command_Line)

... as well as the documentation. So far, SimpInkScr works great but apparently does not work with nodes. I wonder if perhaps Inkscape can somehow write out nodes as points in a file to work with outside Inkscape.

programs used:

- Inkscape v 1.1.2
- Ubuntu Linux 22.04.2
- SimpInkScr: not sure of the latest version number, but it is as of Feb. 21, 2023.

I also just found:

[How can I automatically draw a circle on each node of a path in Inkscape?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/140438/how-can-i-automatically-draw-a-circle-on-each-node-of-a-path-in-inkscape)

update/progress:

.. if this is outside the scope of this user group, I apologize - perhaps Stack Overflow is better - but back to the svg question :

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) describes paths in the svg file. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Basic_Shapes) describes the basic shapes.

I can put circles around nodes in a path by editing the svg file. there are pairs of coordinates. This will work perfectly with command-line tools (`awk,sed,bash`,..) if the relationships between "m", "c", "l",.. and the pairs of coordinates can be maintained. I will try to put an example image up of a testing case - with an errant circle.[image]

relevant svg code snippet for the above image:

```
    <!-- the circle is here
     Inkscape gui says:
     x,y = 50.000,50.000 mm
     W,H = 120.000,120.000 mm
     110.000,110.000 is center and a line node
     110.000,230.000 is where the line ends
     -->
    <circle
       style="fill:none;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:0.262654"
       id="path846"
       cx="110"
       cy="110"
       r="59.868671" />
    <!-- another circle centered on the end of the line with 2r -->
    <circle
       style="fill:none;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:0.262654"
       id="circle5"
       cx="110"
       cy="230"
       r="120" />
    <!-- try circles centered on things -->
    <circle
       style="fill:none;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:0.262654"
       id="circle6"
       cx="154.68248"
       cy="194.63248"
       r="30" />
    <circle
       style="fill:none;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:0.262654"
       id="circle6"
       cx=""
       cy=""
       r="30" />
    <!-- now the path with some nodes -->
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 110,110 38.04426,11.79937 6.63822,72.83311 L 110,230"
       id="path1062"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="cccc" />
    <!-- end of path with some nodes -->
```

Comment: This might help - I discovered this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857818/python-svg-parser - the key idea was thinking about xml or svg parser modules in python. The SO thread has a nifty python script to get paths out of svg files. The site links to https://pypi.org/project/svgpathtools/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/160239/inkscape-dots-points-on-a-curve-line-x-y-coordinates-of-points-in-svg-file/160325#160325) Graphic Design SE post will be very useful for this question. It is still not clear how scripting is handled in Inkscape (e.g. loading a script into a window or some such), but it might not matter because the command-line scripts (amenable to "automation") and Inkscape GUI tools referred to in the linked SE post will be of great value to get/edit/add 1. nodes and 2. calculate plain-text format `x,y` coordinates of a curve or other vector features.