# Inkscape circle/ellipse : marker for center?

Tags: inkscape, vector, snapping

I am moving very large circles in Inkscape, snapping the centers to nodes on another shape (see links below). I have to fish around with the circle to get the snap guide to appear. I have marked the arbitrary shape with markers, so I tried that for the circles, but the markers appear on the perimeter - not the center. When the circle is very large, it is very difficult. With many nodes, it is also difficult to move the pointer to get one node and not another. I am also not sure how I ought to set the node snap weight yet.

an existing post similar to this:

[How can I automatically draw a circle on each node of a path in Inkscape?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/140438/how-can-i-automatically-draw-a-circle-on-each-node-of-a-path-in-inkscape)

links to other posts on a general task this is part of, with an image (but before I learned how to add markers to the shape):

[Inkscape scripting and automation : nodes?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/160213/inkscape-scripting-and-automation-nodes)

Inkscape v. 1.1.2

Ubuntu Linux 22.04

Comment: I honestly don't know for Inkscape, but Illustrator has a toggle in the attributes to show/hide the center point on shapes. There *may be* something similar in Inkscape.

Comment: You could use markers for this. Not sure what you mean by "the markers appear on the perimeter, not the centre". Makers will appear centred on a node.

Comment: Also you can't set a marker on the rotation centre of a circle, because it's not a node. Markers can only go on nodes It might be possible to simply put two overlapping nodes of a small path at the centre of a circle and group it with the circle if you need to visualize the centre as you click and drag. Seems quite a contrivance however.